# Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n -1}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find the limit of the following \begin{equation*} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n -1}{2^n} \end{equation*}

I do not know how to do it, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac1{2^n}$? If yes, that should help you with this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: divide the numerator and the denominator by $2^n$.

Comment: $$\begin{equation*} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n -1}{2^n}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}1-\frac{1}{2^n} \end{equation*}$$

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar Yes, that is a better way of saying it actually :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the limit is 1. Consider division.